# How do I return a value from a nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object which contains data from a WordPress API endpoint. All I want from it is the user's name. But to do that I have to iterate through the following hierarchy:

```
array [
    object {
        object {
            "name": foo
        }
    }
]
```

I tried variations on this but it's not returning what I need.

```
const userList = Object.values(this.state.userList[0]).map(value => {
    const newUserList = Object.values(value).map(value => {
        return value[name];
    });
    return newUserList;
});
```

What's the proper way to navigate an object tree like that?

Comment: `value[name]` should be `value.name`

Comment: Are you sure you need to loop through the object values? Can't you just access a the specific property that contains the object with the name?

Comment: `array.map(o=>o.propname.name)` I don't see any problem?

Comment: @Barmar is right: if you always want to have the first item of your array, then, use `[0]` and then reach your target value directly, no need to make loops. As is, your input data is quite blurry: please add real data structure and expected output, it'll be simpler for everyone to answer your question.

Comment: @sjahan Actually, my comment was related to the `Object.values().map()` loop for the second level.

Comment: @Barmar I think it is the same problem with the first level: you start with a collection: either you want a value for each element or just for the first one (`[0]`). Then, if it is only nested object, let's just reach the data: if the structure is fine and not random, there is no need to loop on that. So no `Object.values().map()`. But maybe we don't understand the real structure of the data right now.